# Multiple REST API with dart

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have **three** JSON APIs are loading in one page but when run its take more time to load the contents  , what is the best way to make it more speed and efficient?

Comment: Future.wait may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/54465973/10685785

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `Streams` to do this.

I would suggest that you take a look at [this article](https://www.burkharts.net/apps/blog/rxdart-magical-transformations-of-streams/) that explains alot on how combine multiple streams.

Doing this, you could have a `repository` class fetching data from your apis. Each of this would return you a `Future` and you could use the method `then()` to push to a stream controller.