# How display data which comes from async function?

Tags: flutter

I use api for get information which need to be display

```
 Future <String> Get_Amount_Jackpot() async {
// SERVER LOGIN API URL
var url2 = 'https://www.easytrafic.fr/game_app/get_jackpot_lotto.php';

// Starting Web API Call.
var response2 = await http.get(url2,headers: {'content-type': 'application/json','accept': 'application/json','authorization': globals.token});

// Getting Server response into variable.

Map<String, dynamic> jsondata2 = json.decode(response2.body);
return jsondata2["value"];


 }
```

I call it here :

```
 void initState() {
ListLotto = Grille_display();
jackpot = Get_Amount_Jackpot();
super.initState();;
```

}
How i can display the value "jackpot" which is a simple number on mobile screen. Note i use futurebuilder for another api request, this is why it is complicated. Normally i use futurebuilder for display async data but there i need 2 différents api request so 2 futureBuilder ??? Is it possible and how do that ?

Comment: i think you might be looking at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54465973/2281066

Answer (score 0):

You can use `then` to get the returned value from the function.

```
Get_Amount_Jackpot().then((value){
//value is what is returned from the function
jackpot = value;
});
```

I'm not sure if you can use uppercase letter as the start of a function name, but i copied your function name for my answer. Hope this helps.