# Multiple images uploading and getting the download urls - Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I'm currently working on uploading multiple images to firebase and getting the `downloadUrl` into a list.

```
  _imageList.forEach((element) async {
                      final StorageReference _ref = FirebaseStorage.instance
                          .ref()
                          .child("Users/ads/"); 
                      StorageUploadTask uploadTask =
                          _ref.putFile(element as i.File);

                      await uploadTask.onComplete;
                      print("Images uploaded");
                      String image_links = await _ref.getDownloadURL();
                      _imageUrls.add(image_links);// _imageUrls is a List
                    });
```

and now I wanna assign the `_imageUrls` into firestore.

```
 Map<String, dynamic> ads = {
                      'adTitle': widget.title,
                      'adPrice': widget.price,
                      'adCategory': widget.dropdownValue,
                      'adCondition': this.newCondtionVal,
                      'adDesc': widget.desc,
                      'user_id': uID,
                      'imageUrls_List': _imageUrls,//Images goes hear

           
                    };
                    crudObj
                        .addData(ads)
                        .then((value) => {
                              showInSnackBar("dataAdded"),
                            })
                        .catchError((e) {
                      print(e);
                    });
```

But the problem is:
uploading data to firestore works first(Image upload is not finished yet), So now `imageUrls_List` slot in firestore is empty.

Is there any way to add `onComplete` to the `getDownloadURL()` function?

or
 any other options to run the **firestore upload** after the images done with uploading?

Comment: How are the two blocks of code related?

Comment: The second block is just right after the first one. and the whole thing is on `onPressed` function.

Comment: Ah. In that case you'll need to wait for all the futures to complete, instead of waiting for each of them individually. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54465359/future-wait-for-multiple-futures for an example