# How to await both future functions at the same time

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
DocumentSnapshot snapshot1 = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc('a')
        .get();

DocumentSnapshot snapshot2 = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc('b')    
        .get();
```

If implemented in this way, the query statements of snapshot2 cannot be executed until all data of snapshot1 is received. It doesn't happen at the same time.

I want to call a function only when both awaits are finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Future.wait([List<Future>])`. Proper usage is described at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54465359/future-wait-for-multiple-futures) answer.

Comment: after Future.wait([List<Future>]). how to use return value? if it is not FutureBuilder?

Comment: If you await entire command like 'final results = await Future.wait([future1, future2])' you'll get List of results for each future. You can acces them like 'final resultFromFirst = results[0]' and so on. You can use this data however you want.