# Get other Futures data even if one Future throws error with Future.wait

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to fetch from multiple Futures in one sitting. So I use Future.wait. But I can't get Future2 value if Future1 throws error.

Is there a solution to this with or without Future.wait ?

```
FutureBuilder(
                  future: Future.wait([Future1,Future2]),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                      case ConnectionState.none:
    
                      case ConnectionState.active:
    
                      case ConnectionState.waiting:
                        return SizedBox(height: 600, child: LoadingIndicator());
                      case ConnectionState.done:
                       // snapshot.data will come as null because there is an error
                        
                        ...
```

Comment: this might be helpful for u:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54465359/future-wait-for-multiple-futures

Answer (score 0):

Use catchError:

```
Future.wait([
  // fake future 1
  Future.delayed(const Duration()).catchError((e) {
    // add your error handler
  }),
  // fake future 2
  Future.delayed(const Duration()).catchError((e) {
    // add your error handler
  }),
]);
```