# Flutter How to show splash screen only while loading flutter data

Tags: flutter, dart, splash-screen

While the app's splash screen is displayed, it needs to download files from the FTP server and process data. Implemented splash screen for flutter

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return FutureBuilder(
      future: Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3)),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
        if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
          return SplashUI();    ///Splash Screen
        else
          return MainUI();       ///Main Screen
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Now, with a delay of 3 seconds, the startup screen is displayed for 3 seconds, during which time the file is downloaded from FTP and data is processed. I want to keep the splash screen until the completion of data processing rather than the specified time.

***Splash Screen***

```
Widget _splashUI(Size size){
    return SafeArea(
      child: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: size.width * 0.5,
          height: size.height * 0.1,
          child: Image(
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
            image: AssetImage('assets/images/elf_logo.png'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

 Widget build(BuildContext context) {

 getFtpFile();
 dataProgress();

 return Platform.isAndroid ?
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: _splashUI(_size),
      ),
    ) :
    CupertinoApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: CupertinoPageScaffold(
        child: _splashUI(_size),
      ),
    );
 }
```

I want to know how to keep SplashScreen while processing data rather than handling SplashScreen with delayed. thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> to keep SplashScreen while `processing data` `rather than` handling
> SplashScreen `with delayed`.

Why not change the delayed?

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _processingData(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
        if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
          return SplashUI();    ///Splash Screen
        else
          return MainUI();       ///Main Screen
      },
    );
  }

  Future<List> _processingData() {
    return Future.wait[
      _getFtpFile(),
      _dataProgress(),
    ];
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you. Your answer solved the problem.

Answer (score 7):

The package [flutter_native_splash](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash) does exactly what you are asking for.
Make a call to `FlutterNativeSplash.preserve()` before your `runApp()` to keep the splash on screen, then `FlutterNativeSplash.remove();` when your download completes:

```
import 'package:flutter_native_splash/flutter_native_splash.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsBinding widgetsBinding = WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  FlutterNativeSplash.preserve(widgetsBinding: widgetsBinding);
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

// when your download is completed, remove the splash screen:
    FlutterNativeSplash.remove();
```

Full disclosure: I maintain this package.

Answer (score 1):

You could do like other people have done in the past; you should make both of your methods **getFTPFile** and **dataProgress** return a **Future**, then you wait for both Futures using **Future.wait**, as in this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54465973/871364

```dart
Future.wait([
   getFTPFile(),
   dataProgress(),     
], () {
  // once all Futures have completed, navigate to another page here
});
```

Comment: thank you. Your answer solved the problem.