# flutter upload multiple images to firebase storage then save url to firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

I want to upload multiple images to Firebase storage. However, the images picked with the image_picker are not all picked at once, instead picked one after the other because they are pictures of specific docs that are supposed to go to specific fields in Firestore.

[How images are uploaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOQ2n.png)

I know how to upload a single doc to the storage and retrieve the url in firestore with this code:

```
File? image;
String? imageUrl = "";
Future<File> customCompressed(
      {required File imagePathToCompress,
      quality = 100,
      percentage = 10}) async {
    var path = await FlutterNativeImage.compressImage(
        imagePathToCompress.absolute.path,
        quality: 100,
        percentage: 60);
    return path;
  }

  Future<File?> pickImage(BuildContext context) async {
    File? image;
    try {
      final pickedImage =
          await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
      if (pickedImage != null) {
        image = File(pickedImage.path);
        File compressedImage =
            await customCompressed(imagePathToCompress: image);
        setState(() {
          image = compressedImage;
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
     print(e);
    }

    return image;
  }

  void selectImage() async {
    image = await pickImage(context);
  }

  upload() async {
    final uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
    var imageFile = File(image!.path);
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
    Reference ref =
        storage.ref().child(childName).child(uid);
    UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(imageFile);
    await uploadTask.whenComplete(() async {
      var url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
      imageUrl = url.toString();
    }).catchError((onError) {
      return onError;
    });
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(collectionName).doc(uid).set({
  "Url": imageUrl!,});
  }
```

How do I upload multiple images(in this case the three images) and to the storage and then upload each image url to Firestore with each image with specific files. Say for example

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(collectionName)
.doc(uid)
.set({
"front_view_of_vehicle": imageUrl1!,
"Vehicle_doc": imageUrl2!,
"Driver_license": imageUrl3!,
});
```

I have tried this but the image file is not created in the Firestore

```
File? image;
  File? image2;
  File? image3;

  String? imageUrl = "";
  String? imageUrl2 = "";
  String? imageUrl3 = "";

  Future<File> customCompressed(
      {required File imagePathToCompress,
      quality = 100,
      percentage = 10}) async {
    var path = await FlutterNativeImage.compressImage(
        imagePathToCompress.absolute.path,
        quality: 100,
        percentage: 60);
    return path;
  }

  Future<File?> pickImage(BuildContext context) async {
    File? image;
    try {
      final pickedImage =
          await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
      if (pickedImage != null) {
        image = File(pickedImage.path);
        File compressedImage =
            await customCompressed(imagePathToCompress: image);

        setState(() {
          image = compressedImage;
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      Utils().awesomeDialogError(context, e.toString(), widget.failedString);
    }

    return image;
  }

  Future<File?> pickImage2(BuildContext context) async {
    File? image2;
    try {
      final pickedImage2 =
          await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
      if (pickedImage2 != null) {
        image2 = File(pickedImage2.path);
        File compressedImage2 =
            await customCompressed(imagePathToCompress: image2);

        // UserInfos().customCompressed(imagePathToCompress: image);

        setState(() {
          image2 = compressedImage2;
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
      Utils().awesomeDialogError(context, e.toString(), widget.failedString);
    }

    return image2;
  }

  Future<File?> pickImage3(BuildContext context) async {
    File? image3;
    try {
      final pickedImage3 =
          await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
      if (pickedImage3 != null) {
        image3 = File(pickedImage3.path);
        File compressedImage3 =
            await customCompressed(imagePathToCompress: image3);

        // UserInfos().customCompressed(imagePathToCompress: image);

        setState(() {
          image3 = compressedImage3;
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
      Utils().awesomeDialogError(context, e.toString(), widget.failedString);
    }

    return image3;
  }

  void selectImage() async {
    image = await pickImage(context);
  }

  void selectImage2() async {
    image2 = await pickImage2(context);
  }

  void selectImage3() async {
    image3 = await pickImage3(context);
  }

  upload() async {
    final uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;

    var imageFile = File(image!.path);
    var imageFile2 = File(image2!.path);
    var imageFile3 = File(image3!.path);

    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
    Reference ref = storage
        .ref()
        .child(childName)
        .child(uid)
        .child(childName)
        .child(uid);

    UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(imageFile);
    UploadTask uploadTask2 = ref.putFile(imageFile2);
    UploadTask uploadTask3 = ref.putFile(imageFile3);
    await uploadTask.whenComplete(() async {
      var url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
      imageUrl = url.toString();
    }).catchError((onError) {
      return onError;
    });
    await uploadTask2.whenComplete(() async {
      var url2 = await ref.getDownloadURL();
      imageUrl2 = url2.toString();
    }).catchError((onError) {
      return onError;
    });
    await uploadTask3.whenComplete(() async {
      var url3 = await ref.getDownloadURL();
      imageUrl3 = url3.toString();
    }).catchError((onError) {
      return onError;
    });
  }
```

Comment: What did you try?  What went wrong with that?  Please edit the question to show what you tried and explain specifically what was the problem with that.

Comment: I have edited what I have tried. Please check

Answer (score 0):

Use `await` **or** `whenComplete`, not both.

With that, your main code for the `upload` function can become:

```
UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(imageFile);
UploadTask uploadTask2 = ref.putFile(imageFile2);
UploadTask uploadTask3 = ref.putFile(imageFile3);

await uploadTask;
var url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
imageUrl = url.toString();
await uploadTask2
var url2 = await ref.getDownloadURL();
imageUrl2 = url2.toString();
await uploadTask3;
var url3 = await ref.getDownloadURL();
imageUrl3 = url3.toString();

// Write imageUrl, imageUrl2, and imageUrl3 to Firestore here
```

And you can then write the URLs to Firestore at the end of those uploads.

---

The above uploads and gets the downloads URLs in sequence. You can speed things up by starting them in parallel, and then [waiting for all futures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54465359/future-wait-for-multiple-futures) to complete.

Comment: Thanks. I did but with the storage I have to save each image seprately to different "child"

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Does the explanation I gave about only using `await` make sense, and does the code in my answer ensure that you can now wait for all three URLs?